# How can I check the color of text in a cell of a worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, epplus

How can I check whether a cell text color is white or any other color in C# epplus WPF?

In VBA the following can be used to check color of cell:

```vb
excelSheet.Cells(row,Column).Characters(1, 1).Font.Color <> vbWhite
```

How can I do the equivalent using epplus?

Comment: excelSheet.Cells(row,Column).Interior.Color. is an RGB integer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you a bit to get deeper into it:

In EPPlus you use richtext, something like this (the code is not tested)

```
if (dataSheet.Cells[1, 1].IsRichText)
{
var x = dataSheet.Cells[1, 1].RichText;
foreach (var g in x) // you will only need the first i think
{
if (g.Color == System.Drawing.Color.White)
{
// Do something
}
}
}
```